# can not create node with Alfresco public Java API, Access Denied. The system is currently in read-only mode

Tags: alfresco

I am developing a module for Alfresco content services community edition version 6.2.0-ga, I can not create nodes by the `NodeService`, but I can create nodes by RestAPI and Share.

this is my java code trying to use `NodeService` to create a dummy node :

```
public EpicDocument upload(EpicDocument doc) {
    logger.info("creating new EpicDocument...");

    StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef(StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE, "SpacesStore");
    NodeRef root = nodeService.getRootNode(storeRef);

    QName type = QName.createQName(EPIC_NAMESPACE_URI, "document");
    Map<QName, Serializable> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ContentModel.PROP_NAME, doc.getPath());
    props.put(QName.createQName(EPIC_NAMESPACE_URI, "fileName"), "FILENAMEEEEEEE132423");
    NodeRef nodeRef = nodeService.createNode(root,
            ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS,
            QName.createQName(NamespaceService.CONTENT_MODEL_1_0_URI, "myNameIsMehrdad"),
            type, props).getChildRef();

    ContentWriter contentWriter = contentService.getWriter(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
    contentWriter.setMimetype(MimetypeMap.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);
    contentWriter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    contentWriter.putContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(doc.getBytes()));

    logger.info("EpicDocument created with NodeRef = {}", nodeRef.toString());
    return doc;
}
```

I get the following error :

```
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.transaction.ReadOnlyServerException: 04100056 Access Denied.  The system is currently in read-only mode.
    at org.alfresco.repo.domain.node.AbstractNodeDAOImpl.getCurrentTransaction(AbstractNodeDAOImpl.java:650)
    at org.alfresco.repo.domain.node.AbstractNodeDAOImpl.newNodeImpl(AbstractNodeDAOImpl.java:1366)
    at org.alfresco.repo.domain.node.AbstractNodeDAOImpl.newNode(AbstractNodeDAOImpl.java:1290)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.createNode_aroundBody24(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:392)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl$AjcClosure25.run(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:1)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:167)
    at org.alfresco.traitextender.RouteExtensions.intercept(RouteExtensions.java:100)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.createNode(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:342)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor204.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.alfresco.repo.lock.mem.LockableAspectInterceptor.invoke(LockableAspectInterceptor.java:244)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.createNode(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor204.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.alfresco.repo.tenant.MultiTNodeServiceInterceptor.invoke(MultiTNodeServiceInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.createNode(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor204.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.alfresco.repo.service.StoreRedirectorProxyFactory$RedirectorInvocationHandler.invoke(StoreRedirectorProxyFactory.java:231)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.createNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.MLPropertyInterceptor.invoke(MLPropertyInterceptor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.invoke(NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.createNode(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor204.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.createNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.mhr.alf.epic.service.EpicContentServiceImpl.upload(EpicContentServiceImpl.java:56)
    at com.mhr.alf.epic.listener.AlfUploadQueueListener.onUpload(AlfUploadQueueListener.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.invoke(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:130)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:196)
```

what is the problem? I have no idea,  Am I Missing Something?

update: do I need to calls `NodeService` method in a transaction (like the sample [here](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-extension-points-public-java-api.html))?!

Comment: From where you called this code ? From webscript or some kind of unit testing?

Comment: this method is called by a Spring `RabbitListener`

Comment: I am using a module extension, alfresco create and initialize my defined Beans.

Comment: do you think that the problem is the too early initialization of my beans? especially the calling bean

Comment: When are you triggering the method? On bean creation or on system initialized?

Comment: I don't understand our question. I said that it is called by rabbit listener when a new message arrives

Comment: you can see the stack trace

Comment: I will try to use transaction, https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-extension-points-public-java-api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was resolved.

as I had guessed, the problem was related to transactions. I was not calling the `upload()` within a transaction.

now, I call the method inside a transaction by using `RetryingTransactionHelper` obtained from `ServiceRegistry`:

```
    NodeRef nodeRef = serviceRegistry.getRetryingTransactionHelper().doInTransaction(
            new RetryingTransactionHelper.RetryingTransactionCallback<NodeRef>() {
                public NodeRef execute() throws Throwable {

                //do work here...
}
}
);
```

note: do not forget to create the Security Context for the calling thread by using `AuthenticationService` 's `authenticate()` method for example.